# How to deliver an additional Python Library with own Plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, installation

For my own plugin I need a special library (pyexiv2) to write a comment into a jpg file (PIL does not do that).
When I want to share my plugin in one of the repositories in the future, what would be a clever or right way to deliver this additional python library, so that my own plugin will work for other people?

Thanks, Micha

Comment: it would be useful to subscribe to qgis dev mailing list(http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer) and asking it over there..

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the discussion over here:

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/How-to-deliver-an-additional-Python-Library-with-own-Plugin-td5028492.html